# PlSql dynamic cursor Creation with input dynamic table name

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hi My PL/SQL function is

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DiffrencesIdentifyerProc(db_nameFirst VARCHAR2,db_nameSecond VARCHAR2,table_name VARCHAR2) IS

dbremort varchar2(100):= db_nameFirst;
dblocal varchar2(100):= db_nameSecond;
tableName varchar2(100) := table_name;

CURSOR cur IS
SELECT * FROM s1.ENTITYFIELDS  MINUS SELECT * FROM s2.ENTITYFIELDS;
BEGIN
FOR e IN cur
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(e.ATTACH_NAME ); 
END LOOP; 
END DiffrencesIdentifyerProc;
```

What I want is in

```
CURSOR cur IS
 SELECT * FROM s1.ENTITYFIELDS  MINUS SELECT * FROM s2.ENTITYFIELDS;
```

Select Part passed paramters to be setted like

```
SELECT * FROM dbremort.dbremort   MINUS SELECT * FROM dbremort.dbremort ;
```

How can I do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build/construct your query to a `varchar2` (or `clob` when on Oracle 11g or newer) variable, then use [native dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102)'s [`open for ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS629) statement for opening the cursor and [`fetch`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fetch_statement.htm#LNPLS01320) statement for fetching from it.

Remember that you'll have to have a statically declared structure for fetching the data into from the cursor, anyway, so your dynamic queries will have to have identical number of selected columns with [identical (or implicitly convertable) data types](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS003).